# Angular 6 - Declaring two component with multiple module in each other

Tags: angular

I have tow component ( C1 && C2), each component has his module file, 
how can i declare C1 in C2 in Angular 6 ?

```
//  Module 1
@NgModule({
imports: [],
exports: [],
declarations: [
    ComponentX,ComponentY
],
providers: []
})

//  Module 2
@NgModule({
imports: [],
exports: [],
declarations: [
    C1,ComponentZ
],
providers: []
})
```

Answer (score 0):

U can only declare a component once in 1 module.

In your case you would import the other component you are missing instead of declaring.

```
//  Module1
@NgModule({
   imports: [],
   exports: [],
   declarations: [
      Component1
   ],
   providers: []
})

//  Module2
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      Module1
   ],
   exports: [],
   declarations: [
      Component2
   ],
   providers: []
})
```